# How to retry method with button click?

Tags: android, dialog, observable, buttonclick, retrywhen

I use an observable method that has dialog and I want to send retry message when failed. But after button clicked, it doesn't send retry message. How can I do it?

```
getCompositeDisposable().add(repository.method().flatMap(resource -> {
      getNavigator().showDialog(new Fragment.Listener() {
          @Override
          public void onPositiveButtonClicked() {
           //observable method
         }

          @Override
          public void onNegativeButtonClicked() {                                                       
            getNavigator().finishActivity();
         }

         }).retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> {
              AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
              return throwableFlowable.takeWhile(e -> {
              return counter.getAndIncrement() != 4;
           }).doOnNext(throwable -> getNavigator().showMessage("Again"));
         })
     }));
```